# How to sort the data in in a twoDimensional array alphabetically?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I am currently having a big issue sorting my Data alphabetically in a 2D array. I'm going to try to give you every detail to be as clear as possible.

Currently, I am fetching my contacts with the CNContactStore. This all works fine. I am able to retrieve all the data I want out of my contacts.

Now, I created the following struct:

```
struct FavoritableContact {
    let contact: CNContact
    var hasFavorited: Bool
}
```

With this, I declared and initialized the following array:

```
var favoritableContacts = [FavoritableContact]()
```

Once I retrieved my contacts, I simply appended them to favoritableContacts;

```
try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stopPointerIfYouWantToStopEnumerating) in

  favoritableContacts.append(FavoritableContact(contact: contact, hasFavorited: false))

})
```

To sort them in alphabetical order in the same array, I simply did the following:

```
 var sortedContacts = favoritableContacts.sorted { $0.contact.familyName < $1.contact.familyName }
```

Now if possible, I want to create the following 2D array,

```
var 2D = [
        [FavoritableContact] //"A"
        [FavoritableContact], //"B"
        [FavoritableContact], //"C"
        [FavoritableContact], //"D"
        ...
    ]
```

I am just not sure how to take my sortedContacts array and separate alphabetically.

I am very new here, If I forgot something, or I didn't do somethign right please let me know.

Comment: Instead of having an array like your 2D one you created above, it seems like it would make more sense to create a dictionary to hold the alphabetized contacts. So create a dictionary where the keys are the letters ("a", "b", "c", etc...) and the values are a FavoritableContact array that is sorted alphabetically. You can create this dictionary by looping through your contacts and check the first letter of the familyName.

Comment: Thats something I was trying to do. But I am looking forward to putting the contacts in a tableview. Therefore, i would use section and row to iterate through the 2D array and display it on the tableview.

Comment: You could still use a dictionary as your datasource for your tableView.  You could simply use an array with the alphabet to keep an ordered list of the letters, and in your tableView methods you can get the count of the array for the key "A", for example, to know how many "A" contacts you have, etc.

Comment: A datasource for a tableview need not be an array. In fact a dictionary is a pretty common datasource for a tableview collection. In your case, I assume the sections would be the first letters (A-Z) and the rows would the arrays that are stored as values in your dictionary. A section would be empty if the key didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, a dictionary with first letters as keys is probably the better way to go as it is much easier to access, though perhaps you have a reason for wanting to use a 2d array instead.  To achieve that you could do something like this:

```
//Create an empty array filled with 26 arrays of FavorableContact
var array2d = Array<[FavoritableContact]>(repeating: [FavoritableContact](), count: 26)

//Find the ascii value for "A" to use as your base
let aAscii = Int("A".unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])  //This returns 65, btw, so you could also just hardcode

//Go through your original array, find the first letter of each contact, and append to the correct array
favoritableContacts.forEach { (contact) in

    //Get the ascii value for the first letter
    let firstLetter = Int(contact.contact.familyName.prefix(1).uppercased().unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value })[0])

    //Append to the array for this letter by subtracting the ascii value for "A" from the ascii value for the uppercased version of this letter.
    array2d[firstLetter - aAscii].append(contact)
}
```

This is not the cleanest thing in the world, and it assumes standard English language alphabet with no diacritics, symbols, numbers or anything else.  Assuming that is true it gets the job done.

Comment: This was it man.. thx a lot! although, can you elaborate more on how you dealed with aAscii? I don't get that line! thxxx!

Comment: No everyone's name start with latin script's A-Z.

Comment: @JavierV. Yes: the ascii value for A is 65, B is 66, etc.  So since we need to translate the alphabet to the array indices for the alphabet we need to make A 0, B 1, etc.  So once we know A is 65 we can subtract 65 from the ascii value for each letter to achieve this.  You could also just make a bigger array to hold all ascii possibilities and then you don't have to do this, but my code was just an example.  You might need to think more about this since other characters might show up, but this will get you started.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I mentioned that in my answer as well.  This is not meant to be a comprehensive solution - just an example of how the asker may get started.

Comment: @creeperspeak Perfect man! Right now, I was able to check for every character in the ascii table and available on the keyboard. The only problem is that I'm missing other languages and emojis! How could I deal with that?

Comment: This is where using a 2D array is going to hurt you.  If you need to be able to use non-ascii characters, like emoji and letters with accents, etc. you will need to be using a dictionary as this will allow you to handle unicode characters.  Check out the other answers for easy solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Could use something like this.

```
var contactsLeftToSort : [FavoritableContact] = []
var doubleArray : [[FavoritableContact]?] = [[FavoritableContact]?]()

var index : Int = 0

for char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV" {
    doubleArray.append(nil)
    var i = 0
    while i < contactsLeftToSort.count {
        let contact = contactsLeftToSort[i]
        if contact.name.first == char {
            doubleArray[index] == nil ? doubleArray[index] = [contact] : doubleArray[index]!.append(contact)
            contactsLeftToSort.remove(at: i)
        }

        //assuming original list is alphabetized.. if not, delete this line.
        if contact.name.first! > char { break }
        i += 1
    }
    index += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments above, I think you can achieve this in a much more elegant way by using a dictionary instead of an array.

**SWIFT 4**

```
let sortedContacts: [FavoritableContact] = ... // An array of FavoritableContact objects, they should be sorted
let groupedContacts = Dictionary(grouping: contacts, by { $0.familyName.first! })
```

You now have a dictionary of all your contacts where the keys are the alphabetical letters (ie. A-Z) and the values are arrays of sorted FavoritableContact objects (assuming you sorted the big array of FavoritableContacts before creating the dictionary).

If you wanted to use this as the datasource for your tableview, you would make the number of sections all the possible first letters of family names. For the number of rows in each section, you return the count of the array for the key like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    let letterForSection = letterForSection() // Custom method to get the section of the letter
    return contactsDict[letterForSection].count
}
```

The rest of the datasource methods would work in a similar way.

Comment: I'm following a video on youtube to do this. I just added somethign to my code, i will create a new post! thx for the info tho. I will paste the new post here. Thanks man. i've been at this for at least 5 hrs... I'm a new programmer. cheers!

Comment: There is already `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` which does what you have in that loop

Comment: @Alexander I updated my answer at the exact same time you posted this! Just learned about that method this morning, it's super useful.

Answer (score 0):

Man, all of these answers are really over-complicating this. All you need is something along the lines of:

```
let groupedContacts = Dictionary(grouping: contacts, by: { $0.contact.firstName.first! })


for initial, contacts in groupedContacts.lazy.sorted().{ $0.key < $1.key} {
    print("#################", initial)
    contacts.forEach{ print($0) }
}
```